# Excel VSTO chart.mouseup event not firing

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am creating an application level addin for Excel using Excel Interop. Here is my setup:

```
Dim NativeSheet as Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
Dim vstoSheet as Worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(NativeSheet)
Dim vstoChart as Chart = vstoSheet.Controls.AddChart(left:=50, top:=50, width:=50, height:=50, name:="Membrane")
```

I then add three event handlers: for MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp.

```
Private Sub _vstoChart_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer) Handles _vstoChart.MouseUp
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Up")
End Sub

Private Sub _vstoChart_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer) Handles _vstoChart.MouseDown
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Down")
End Sub

Private Sub _vstoChart_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer) Handles _vstoChart.MouseMove
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Move")
End Sub
```

The trouble is, it works for MouseDown and MouseMove, but the MouseUp event doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: I seem to remember that the on click event gets called before mouse up on worksheet , u may need to cancel that click event so the up fires

Comment: @StevenMartin: Not sure what you mean. There is no Click event on worksheets.

Comment: sorry i meant on chart sheets , a click fires the activate event ,