# Excel Chart_MouseUp event not trapped

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to trap the `Mouse` events associated with an Excel chart using Excel VBA, in particular when the user presses left button-shift-ctrl using the mouse and keyboard.  The `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events work fine but the `MouseUp` event does not.  The code is as follows:

```
Dim iflag As Boolean

Private Sub Chart_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    If Button = vbKeyLButton Then
        If Shift = 3 Then
            iflag = True
            Application.StatusBar = "MouseDown pressed"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Chart_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    If Button = vbKeyLButton Then
        If Shift = 3 Then
            If iflag Then
                Application.StatusBar = Application.StatusBar & "; now moving mouse"
                iflag = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Chart_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    If Button = vbKeyLButton Then
        If Shift = 3 Then
            Application.StatusBar = Application.StatusBar & "; MouseUp pressed"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

PS I think this is related to the following query which was not answered:
[[Excel VSTO chart.mouseup event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682113/excel-vsto-chart-mouseup-event-not-firing][1])

Comment: Do you have any COM add-ins installed? Does the `MouseUp` event work if you run Excel in Safe Mode?

Comment: Hi Rory - no COM add-ins installed in EXCEL and the MouseUp event does not work when XL is running in safe mode

Comment: It works for me. Er, quick question... (To make sure we are on the same page; please bear with me) How do you think the "Chart_MouseUp" works?

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Rory: I am using Office 365; Siddharth: I think XL fires a MouseDown event when the mouse button is clicked, fires MouseMove events when the mouse is moved with a mouse button clicked and a MouseUp event when the mouse button is released

Comment: Thank You. Can you please try this for me. **[1.]** Put a break point on `Private Sub Chart_MouseUp` **[2.]** Left Click on one of the pie/bar etc and then press shift+ctrl and then release. Does the line get highlighted?

Comment: Sorry @Rory. Just realized that I hijacked the comments.

Comment: @SiddharthRout no problem - have at it! :)

Comment: Btw. you can make this a bit cleaner by using IFs that exit the code instead of enclosing If's: For example: `If Not(Button = vbKeyLeft) Then Exit Sub` or `If Shift <> 3 Then Exit Sub`, using `Not` or `<>` is personal taste. This way you can keep your nesting to a minimum, heck you could even do `If Button <> vbKeyLeft or Shift <> 3 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Hi Siddharth.  I am working with an XY chart but think I get your drift.  If I left click the y-axis, hold down shift-ctrl and then release the mouse button, then the MouseUp event gets fired and execuion stops at the breakpoint in that module

Comment: That means the code is working...

Comment: Ok ... but if I press shift-ctrl, then click left mouse button, keep it pressed, then move mouse and then release the left mouse button, execution does not pass through the 'Chart_MouseUp' function.  I need to trap the mouse release so it is quite possible that I am confused about the various events

Comment: Till the time you are moving inside the chart (axes, data point etc) as you mentioned above, It will work. If you go out of the chart (The white area), It will not work.

Comment: Hi @Siddharth not sure what to say - I am only moving the mouse inside the chart area and in my case execution does not pass through the Chart_MouseUp when I implement the series of key presses described above

Comment: For further testing, comment out the code for `MouseMove and Down` Ensure your application.Statusbar says "Ready". Now test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197885/discussion-between-petgriffin-and-siddharth-rout).