# Excel Chart_MouseUp event not trapped under the same scenario trapped by the corresponding MouseDown event

Tags: excel, vba, mouseevent

I have exactly the same problem of the question [Excel Chart_MouseUp event not trapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479298/excel-chart-mouseup-event-not-trapped) but there no answer has been given

I'm interested in the sequence press shift-ctrl-left mouse (MouseDown event is fired), move left mouse (MouseMove event is fired), release shift-ctrl-left mouse (MouseUp event is NOT fired)

How is it possible that a MouseDown event is fired and the corresponding MouseUp event Not (under the same circumstances)!!!

How can I solve the issue?

Thanks in advance for the help you can give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if no answer I received here about this topic, hoping this could be usefull for others, I append a solution given to me by Peter Thornton, which I thank a lot for the suggestions given.

There is a different way, not sure why I didn’t think of it before --> check the state of the left mouse button with a timer

Below my code written for purpose

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const HWND_ZERO As LongPtr = 0
Private Const TIMER_MILLISECS = 150&

Private Const VK_LBUTTON = &H1 'Left mouse button
Private Const VK_RBUTTON = &H2 'Right mouse button
Private Const SM_SWAPBUTTON = 23& 'Left and Right mouse buttons are logically swapped (Left mouse button is the default Primary button)

Private mTimerID As LongPtr

Public Sub StartTimer()
' call StartTimer in the chart's MouseDown event
    If mTimerID Then
        Call EndTimer
    End If

    mTimerID = SetTimer(HWND_ZERO, mTimerID, TIMER_MILLISECS, AddressOf TimerProcedure)
End Sub

Private Function TimerProcedure() As LongPtr
    Dim Ch As Chart
    Dim obj As Variant

    Dim ret As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    If mTimerID = 0 Then
        Call EndTimer
    Else
        'map the mouse logical Primary Button to the mouse phisical Left or Right Buttons
        If Not GetSystemMetrics32(SM_SWAPBUTTON) Then ret = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) Else ret = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)

        'the condition is satisfied if the mouse Left Button state is correctly trapped and the Left Button is released
        If Not ret And 32768 Then
            Call EndTimer
            mTimerID = 0

            Call UserDefinedChartMouseUp() procedure

        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub EndTimer()
    On Error Resume Next

    Call KillTimer(HWND_ZERO, mTimerID)
End Sub
```